# Default handler in Micronaut controller

Tags: micronaut

I have a micronaut controller

```
...
@Controller("/**")
public class MainController {

  @Get(value="/path1")
  public HttpResponse handlePath1Get(HttpRequest<?> request) {

    .. do something ..
  }

  @Get(value="/path1/action1")
  public HttpResponse handlePath1Action1(HttpRequest<?> request) {

    .. do something else ..
  }
}
```

The calls to these specific end-points work fine.

However now I have a requirement that all the paths (other than the specific ones above) need to be delegated to a single handler. Is there a way by which this can be achieved?

I am currently using Micronaut v1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a variable that includes reserved characters

```
  @Get(value="/{+path}")
  public HttpResponse handleAnyUri(String path) {

    .. do something else ..
  }
```

The value of `path` for a request to `/hello/world` will be `hello/world`

Comment: Thanks. Quick question though, can I use @Get(value="/path1") and the @Get("/{+path}") in the same Controller (separate handlers) ? Would there be a resolution conflict?

Comment: There would not be a resolution conflict. A request to `/path1` would hit the first one and all others would hit the second